# Passing Metadata While Generating Stripe Payment Link

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to pass a few app specific credentials with stripe url for checkout.

I tried something like the following,

```
  const paymentLink = await stripe.paymentLinks.create({
    line_items: [{price: "price_1XXXXK", quantity: 1}],
    metadata: {
        author_id: "author_id",
        server_id: "server_id",
    },
    
  });
```

But in payments tab, the metadata is still empty.

I can only see those metadata in generated payment link section. But I can't find any relations or references about the link that was used to make the purchase on the payment response data.

So is there any better way to add metadata to the checkout while creating a payment link, instead of adding metadata just for the generated link?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `metadata` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-metadata) when creating a Payment Link will only persist on the generated Checkout Session object, and **not** the underlying payment:

> Metadata associated with this Payment Link will automatically be copied to checkout sessions created by this payment link.

> But I can't find any relations or references about the link that was used to make the purchase on the payment response data.

To reconcile the Payment Intent [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) with the associated Payment Link that was the origin of the payment:

1. List all Checkout Sessions, passing the `payment_intent` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent).
2. Expand the `payment_link` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_link) on the returned Checkout Session object.

Comment: So.. is there any other straight forward way to pass metadata to the underlying payment during link creation? Or manually fetching the payment link reference and then making another request to fetch metadata of the payment link is the only way?

Comment: You can't set the metadata on the payment directly from a Payment Link no. You could setup a webhook handler for this: listen for `checkout.session.completed` events and the update the associated Payment Intent/Charge with the metadata fields from the Checkout Session object.

Answer (score 0):

The Create method for Checkout Sessions supports these parameters:

- payment_intent_data

  - metadata passed this way will be available in both `payment_intent.succeeded` and `charge.succeeded` events.
- setup_intent_data
- subscription_data

That let you pass data to the underlying payment_intent/setup_intent/subscription objects and it supports metadata.

So you'd be able to pass metadata to, say, a PaymentIntent this way.

See: https://support.stripe.com/questions/using-metadata-with-checkout-sessions

---

In passing / rant: most people will need to use metadata so as to get an "easy" way to know which products are in the order, because out of the box the Stripe API does NOT tell you, in an event, which product was ordered  (except [for Payment Links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63550876/1717535)).